# microsoft dynamics crm - SQL changes

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Hi I'm facing a task that requires me (or not?) to do some small changes directly on the CRM SQL DB.

Situation: 
1) there was a N:1 relation between two entities that was changed to N:N. 
2) For each entities I need to move related stuff from previous relation to new one.

For active entities it was no problem cause customer didn't care about changing fields "ModifiedOn", "ModifiedBy" and "ClosedOn" but for inactive (an incident that is closed for example) he'd like to migrate the related entities, but not to change these three fields. Because all those incidents are closed/inactive I cannot just call "AssociateRequest" I need to re-open case, associate, close it again. this of course will change these fields.

Is there any way to do this via the API and not directly on SQL? If not - could it be a problem?

Comment: Creating N:N relationships based on an N:1 relationship through SQL is unsupported by Microsoft.  However past that it is a simple and fast way to solve your problem.  I certainly recommend making this change first in a testing environment to verify.

Comment: the relation is already created and active entities were associated via CRM API. What I want to do with inactive stuff is to re-open cases, associate them with these entities and close again via API. the only thing that I want to write directly in the SQL are values for the fields "ModifiedOn", "ModifiedBy" and "ClosedOn" (incident entity). So you're saying it should be ok to do this? Of course will do tests first on test environment

Comment: You could store your table metadata fields in a temp table, run the API operation, and then restore those fields in CRM.  This shouldn't cause any issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the mechanism to change the Relationship and just need to modify the records CreatedOn, CreatedBy, ModifiedOn, and ModifiedBy...You should be able to do this using [late bound code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328416.aspx):

```cs
Entity YourTargetEntity= new Entity("YourTargetEntity");
YourTargetEntity["createdon"] = new DateTime(2015,01,01); // or whatever the date you want
YourTargetEntity["overriddencreatedon"] = new DateTime(2015,01,01); // or whatever the date you want
YourTargetEntity["createdby"] = new EntityReference("systemuser", new Guid("XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"));
TargetEntity["modifiedby"] = new EntityReference("systemuser", new Guid("XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"));
TargetEntity["modifiedon"] = new DateTime(2015,01,01); // or whatever the date you want
_service.Update(YourTargetEntity);
```

Hope that helps.